# Parallelograms in a convex hexagon

Tags: geometry, polygons

If you have a (convex) hexagon, and label it ABCDEF, and if ACDF is a parallelogram, and ABDE is a parallelogram, prove that BCEF is a parallelogram also.

Comment: Midpoints of AD, CF coincide, and so do midpoints of AD, BE, so midpoints of CF and BE coincide.

Answer (score 0):

Choose an origin $O$. Opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal vectors. You therefore have the vector equations:

$OC-OA=OD-OF$ and $OD-OC=OF-OA$ from the first, equivalent to $OC+OF=OA+OD$

$OB-OA=OD-OE$ and $OD-OB=OE-OA$ from the second, equivalent to $OB+OE=OA+OD$

And for the third you need $OC-OB=OE-OF$ and $OE-OC=OF-OB$, equivalent to $OC+OF=OB+OE$

Comment: nice solution! Do you have one not involving vectors?

Comment: @sukamakisukamaki This is equivalent to Wojowu's comment. But vectors here are natural and systematic.

Comment: Oh ok! I kind of understand